# Can't seem to get images, text, etc. to appear next to my vertical navigation menu

Tags: html, css, layout, formatting, format

I'm attempting to build a website for the first time, and I'm running into some trouble getting the layout correct.

I want image links (and any other content I attempt to put on the page) to appear to the right of my menu without disrupting it. It seems to always appear below it or insert itself between the logo image and the menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the page in question as it stands is below... pardon the likely poorly written html.

```css
  .vertical-menu {
  width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: white;
}

div.spacer {
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0px;
  line-height: 0;
}

div {
  border: 0px solid black;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: white;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>

  <center>
    <h1 style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;">music etc.</h1>
  </center>

  <div class=“panel”>
    <left>
      <img src=img/glassparklogodraft1yellow.png height=215 width=215>
    </left>

  </div>

  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class=“panel”>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </div>

  <body>

    <div class="vertical-menu">
      <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=main.html>home</a>
      <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=magazine.html>magazine</a>
      <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=visual.html>visual content</a>
      <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=audio.html>audio</a>
      <a style="font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;" href=contact.html>contact</a>
    </div>


  </body>

  <body>
    <center>
      <p>2nd floor - the fabled sound
        <p>

          <a href=gpmaudio/2ndfloorthefabledsound.zip download>

            <img src=img/fabledsoundcover.png width=200 height=200>

          </a>
    </center>
  </body>

  <div class=“spacer”></div>

  <body>
    <center>
      <p>2nd floor - the lebron bonus
        <p>

          <a href=gpmaudio/2ndfloorthelebronbonus.zip download>

            <img src=img/lebronbonuscover.jpg width=200 height=200>

          </a>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Some things: HTML content does not belong in the head, `<left>` isn't a valid tag, `<center>` is deprecated, many things such as your link URLs should be in quotes, there should only be one body, paragraphs are closed with `</p>`, you should probably use HTML5 instead of XHTML, especially as XHTML is very strict and you aren't following it at all. Plain ol' HTML has some leeway for error, XHTML doesn't so much.

Comment: Maybe you could include a screenshot of what your HTML produces, and an illustration of what you're trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ETUbKsg

Comment: The first image is what my code produces, the 2nd image is what I want in terms of layout.

Answer (score 2):

Add CSS property, `position` to the `vertical-menu` class and set it to `absolute`

```
.vertical-menu {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Find more information on CSS position property here on [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Comment: Alright, it did move everything up a little bit thank you. Now the problem is the logo image. How can I apply the same to the logo image that rests just above the menu?

Comment: Do you want the logo to be positioned along the right hand side of the menu?

Comment: No, I want the logo above the menu, both resting on the left side.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ETUbKsg the first image is what I'm getting, the 2nd is what I want in terms of layout. The menu and logo are more or less in the right spot, however the content of the webpage isn't showing up next to it correctly.